# A pendulum consists of a rod with length L and a coin of mass m

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, conservation-laws, potential-energy

> A pendulum consists of a rod with length $L$ and a coin of mass $m$. The pendulum is held in a horizontal position and then is released with a minimum velocity needed to make a full circle.
>
> What's the maximum kinetic energy of the coin? What's the tension on the rod when kinetic energy is at its maximum

By the laws of conservation I think it is: $KE(\textrm{at the maximum height})-KE+PE=0$, and by substitution turns out that minimum velocity to make a full circle is $v=\sqrt{5gL}$. I think that when the rod is released from the horizontal position, the maximum kinetic energy is at the lowest point. The tension on the rod I think it's $T=m(g+a)$.

I don't know if my equations are correct but even if they are, I'm finding hard to relate them.

Comment: This is homework but you've made some attempt, so: the KE at the top is 0 (only true because it's a rod, not a string), the PE at the bottom is 0, energy is conserved, so this tells you the KE at the bottom, and hence the velocity at the bottom and hence the radial acceleration at the bottom and hence the tension.